# Does the last villager trade allways boost your reputation in village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I keep buying the last item options from villagers.

[image: image description]

The Wiki states on [trading and popularity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#popularity):

> ```
> Action                                                        Popularity Change
> Trading a villager for the last offer slot on their list      +1
> ```

Does that mean that if I buy 20 name-tags my popularity will be 20? Or, since popularity caps at 10, does that mean I can allways just buy 10 nametags to fix any popularity deficit due to killing villagers or iron golems?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, because trading in the last slot is the only option to increase your popularity. because the popularity can range from -30 to 10, you would need to buy 40 nametags (or any other item in the last slot) to ensure your popularity is maxed out.