# MCPE iron golems not losing aggro

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been building up a village in Minecraft PE and it started spawning iron golems. I was killing the golems for their iron and I injured a few villagers while mining now the golems won't stop attacking me.

My difficulty has been set to Peaceful for as long as I've been working on the village.

I've tried the following:

1. Exited to the main menu
2. Force quit the app
3. Killed all the iron golems in the village
4. Stayed away from the villagers and iron golems for a long time

   - I kept the villagers and golems fenced off while I did a lot of work
   - I didn't leave the village chunk or its adjacent chunks, though

They don't chase me very far and, on rare occasion, I can walk right past them without drawing aggro.

Is there anything I can do to stop them from attacking me?

Comment: Interesting side note: the golems' attack seems to depend entirely on their ability to throw you into the air. They're all spawning in a 5-meter high area and they can't damage me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you accidentally attacked a villager or two, your popularity in the village is probably low enough that the Iron Golems will attack you on sight.

One option is to prevent more Iron Golems from [spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Spawning), and then killing any remaining ones aggressive towards you in the village. You should theoretically be able to prevent them from spawning by either reducing the village population to fewer than ten villagers, or by reducing the number of homes (a home can be removed by deleting the wooden door—the structure itself does not need to be demolished) to fewer than 21.

Once you have prevented the Golems from spawning, you can attempt to increase your popularity with the villagers, to prevent any golems that spawn in the future—because of population increase/home construction—from being hostile. The only way I know of to increase popularity with villagers is to trade with them, specifically [for their last item](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#Popularity) ([related Arqade question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223844/does-the-last-villager-trade-allways-boost-your-reputation-in-village)).

Another option, if you don't care about the village at all, is to wipe out the village's population, resetting your popularity for that village.

*Disclaimer: I have not tried the aforementioned solutions myself, so I cannot guarantee they will work.*

Comment: According to the [Pocket Edition wiki](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Trading), trading hasn't been implemented yet. If I wiped the entire population, would any villagers ever spawn again?

Comment: Oh jeese, I didn't realize it wasn't implemented in PE. I don't believe the villagers will spawn again, unfortunately. That's why I mentioned it was only really an option if you didn't care about the village at all, and only wanted those golems to stop attacking...

Comment: No problem. It looks like there isn't a popularity mechanism in PE (as far as I can tell) so I'm removing most of the doors, killing off most of the villagers, letting them breed, then killing the adults. The goal there is to get rid of any villagers I've ever damaged without completely eliminating the population.

Comment: I took your suggestions but modified them a little so I'll give you the credit for the accepted answer. I'm going to put my process as a separate answer, though, since I need more room to do that.

Comment: A note I should point out regarding the popularity: you also lose popularity points for punching a golem and for killing a golem. This includes any Golems that you spawned yourself within the village's boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your skin, making them think you're not the same person I tried it and it worked even after I killed a villager

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to pushasha for putting me on the right track. I just want to make sure my process gets put on the record here.

1. Kill all of the iron golems
2. Kill all but two of the villagers. Hopefully the remaining two won't ever have been injured.
3. Go far from the village. If I had to guess, I'd say I was .5 to 1 kilometers away.
4. Stay away for a while - I spent an hour or more without getting any closer.

I went back at this point and once golems started spawning again, they didn't attack me.

I *think* the problem is that there were injured villagers which polled as village members during the [census](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding) which, in turn, contributed to a large enough population to cause golems to spawn. Those golems were mad at me because of the hurt villagers who said they lived in that village.

Again, that's just a guess. One way or the other, the golems stopped attacking me after I followed the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the golems keep attacking you has to do with your popularity in the village.
Every time you kill a golem or you hit a villager your popularity goes down.

To increase my popularity, I first set the game to "peaceful" mode.
I used the time in this mode to build up my popularity again by trading with the villagers.
Just to be safe I also put the golems that were present on a leash.
Finally, I switched back to normal mode and 'after a lot of trading', they weren't hostile any more.